# How to identify the printed results of my program so I can send them to myself

Tags: python, smtp, twilio

I'm new to Python, and I just wrote a little program that will randomly select my daily task from a list. I want to send the results to myself every morning using Twilio or email (I haven't decided which yet). The problem I've run into is that I don't know how to identify the printed results for the program, since the results themselves don't appear in the IDE, only in the shell. I know this is a total noob question, but how should I identify for the program the results that I want to email to myself?

```
import random
todo = ['one chapter of nonfiction', 'one chapter of math', '30 minutes of songwriting', 'one lesson of Python', '30 minutes of game design', 'one chapter of nonfiction']
book = ['Cosmos', 'A Brief History of Time', 'The Universe in a Nutshell', 'The Origin of Species', '30-Second Mythology', 'The Cartoon Guide to Physics', 'Mankind: The Story of All of Us', 'Murderous Minds', 'Frauds, Myths, and Mysteries', 'Kraken', 'Behaviourism: Classic Studies', 'Philosophy Questions and Answers', 'Ethics', 'The Potter\'s Freedom', 'The Essential Jung', 'The Institutes of Christian Religion', 'On Writing', 'Writing Better Lyrics', 'This Book Will Make You Think', 'Plato\'s Podcasts', 'The 15-Minute Psychologist', 'Philosophy: Who Needs It?', 'The Farther Reaches of Human Nature', 'Exploring the Deep Frontier', 'Picture Atlas of Our Universe', 'Walden', 'The Basic Writings of Bertrand Russell', 'Meditations', 'The Republic', 'The Dialogues of Socrates', 'On Liberty']
print('Good morning!')
todos = random.choice(todo)
books = random.choice(book)
print('Your activity today is %s.' % todos)
if todos == 'one chapter of nonfiction':
    print ('You will read one chapter from "%s."' % books)
print ('Have a great day!')
```

[Here's what the shell prints out for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adUWS.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to send the result to yourself by email, then store the result in a variable instead of printing it. E.g. 
Result = 'your activity today is {}'.format(todos)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So rather than printing something, I should have it interpreted as a variable somehow.